# Can a static property of a static class be a DataMember of a BindingSource?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, data-binding, static, bindingsource

I have static class that has a bunch of static properties.  When I try to bind the property to a BindingSource (in the UI), I can pick the static class as the DataSource, however, when I drop down the DataMember combo, there is nothing there.

Can I use a static property of a static class as a DataMember of a BindingSource?

I should mention that this is a Winforms project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Most data-binding uses `System.ComponentModel` / `TypeDescriptor`, which is intrinsically instance based. You *could*, however, shim the static properties through a dummy object if you *really* wanted.

Note that additional care should be taken re thread-safety of static properties, which may make them even less desirable for direct data-binding.  (or better: the use of mutable static properties should be heavily limited)

Comment: Thanks.  The static properties are safely shielded from thread-safety shenanigans.